# JavaFX runtine components are missing?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, jar, artifact

Hello i try to build an artifact but they say:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtxIx.png)

i try to add maven dependency on the projetstructure, but that doesn t work.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJsSS.png) what can i do ?

Thanks a lot for your answers

Comment: Please, [no images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/230513).

Comment: Follow one of the tutorials [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

Answer (score 0):

Which version of java do you use?, normally after the version 11 of Java, JavaFx is no more part of the lib.
You need to download apart go here (https://openjfx.io/), if you use version 9 please made this:
`java --module-path /path/of/javafx-sdk-XX/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar YourApp.jar` java and javafx most be compatible also

Comment: I add in the artifacts project structure, the path to the lib javafx 20, to the bin javafx 20. i had in the edit configurations ->VM options : --module-path "C:\Program Files (x86)\javafx-sdk-20.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml.   I can start the artifact jar file from intellij without error now, but when i want to launch the jar file in explorer, they say: "A Java Exception has occured"

Comment: do you set the values in your enviroment variable too?